# What is the best way to automate my linux setup

Tags: bash, home-directory, .desktop, git

At work, I had to rebuild my WSL a number of times and I was wondering what will be the best way to automate my Ubuntu setup. For .dotfiles files, I'm using the bare-git approach (`https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/dotfiles`) but when it comes to package installation or system wide config I wonder what other people are doing?

Is the best way is to use a simple bash script or Ansible or another way??

Feedback greatly appreciated

Oren

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a plain script. Easy to comment, troubleshoot, and backup.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For system-wide config, etckeeper is a nice tool that integrates git.